# How can I use Sencha Touch widgets along with regular HTML "widgets"?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a page that I would like to use some sencha items on along with some non-sencha html.

So the page might be...(after loading sencha headers)

```
<div id="banner"><h1>@if (Model != null)
{@Model.DisplayName}</h1></div>
<div style="background-color: #CFE1E8; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; ">
<div id="buttonDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/widgets/button.js"></script>
<div id="searchDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/widgets/search.js"></script>
<div id="carouselDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/widgets/carousel.js"></script>
<div id="panelDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/widgets/panel.js"></script>
</div>
```

Each of the js files contains some sencha code to render the control into the associated div.  For example:

```
Ext.setup({
    fullscreen: false,
    onReady: function () {
        var panel = new Ext.Panel({
            title: 'Message Title',
            fullscreen: false,
            renderTo: 'buttonDiv',
            defaults: {
                // applied to each contained item
                width: 120

            },
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Click Me',
                handler: function () {
                alert("You Clicked Me...");
            }
}
]
        });
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when the page is taller than the width of the phone, anytime I touch the screen, the page immediately jumps to the bottom of the page.  The normal page scrolling doesn't work at all.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing two things:

- Added an Ext.util.Scroller on the body.  There's a bug with the Ext.util.Scroller on iPhones that it won't actually let you scroll upwards.  Works fine on Androids though.
- "Registered" the content of each module's js as a function by pushing to a global variable so that it would get added in the head and then executed them all in a loop, so I only ran Ext.Setup once.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your components a layout and possibly a flex, e.g.:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
```

and

```
flex: 1
```

For scrolling, you could try:

```
scroll: 'vertical'
```

Also, another way of using HTML inside sencha is to use the html property in your components, e.g:

```
new Ext.Panel({
    scroll: 'vertical',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    flex: 1

    items: [{
        html: 'HTML content inside a panel',
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm not able to relegate my html code inside of panels for weird reasons.

Adding layouts, flex, and scroll to the components make each individual component scrollable, but I am still not able to scroll through the various components.  Also, the page still automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page after loading.